# Dynamo DB streams, update the latest stream ARN

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

My application reads a dynamoDB stream to look for changes to a table and I am currently getting the most recent stream like this:

```
this.awsDB.describeTable({TableName: 'MatchDraft'}, function(err, data){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    this.streamArn = data.Table.LatestStreamArn;
    console.log(data, this.streamArn);
    _readStream.apply(this);
  }
}.bind(this));
```

The problem I am running into is that the tables LatestStreamArn does not update on its own and expires every 24 hours, at which point my program starts working.  I am ALWAYS using only the "LATEST" shard iterator type so I don't want to keep a 24 hour record of all changes, I just want to be able to use shard iterators to detect changes to the table efficiently and display them as they occur.

How can I make my application automatically just create a new LatestStreamArn as needed in the most efficient way?  The code is all client side in the users web browser so I don't want to open up permissions for the UpdateTable API which as far as I know is the only way to update the stream.

Comment: why are you not using AWS Lambda?

Comment: @EyalCh I guess because aside from this one issue that seems as though it ought to be trivial, I have no need for it.  How specifically would lambda be helpful?  It seems like the way things are now I just need a chron job that calls update table every 24 hours and there is no other solution.  Would lambda have a cleaner way to solve this?  What specifically would you do with it?

Comment: @Eyal Ch If lambda would help I'd definitely love to know how.  Even with allowing an UpdateTable call, my stream seems to just no longer be active after a certain time.  The only way I can make my application resume working is to disable the stream via updateTable and re-enable it :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latestStreamArn does not expire after 24 hours. A stream is created when you enable DynamoDB Streams either through a CreateTable or UpdateTable API call.

latestStreamArn will change if you disable a DynamoDB stream and then re-enable it.

Calling GetShardIterator with ShardIteratorType LATEST can cause you to lose data because there is no guarantee that the last GetRecords response included all records up until that point.

In order to track the changes from DynamoDB Streams you need to do a few things in practice:

1. Enable the stream - you only need to call DescribeTable once after this to get the latestStreamArn (your application can call this once at startup).
2. Periodically call DescribeStream to get the shard list. Using the parentShardId pointers in each shard, you can construct a lineage of shards. If you want to process the changes in order, you must fully process a shard before processing any of its descendants.
3. Call GetShardIterator once when beginning to process a shard. You can use a TRIM_HORIZON shard iterator type if you want to process all events. Otherwise you can initialize your application by processing the latest shards (the latest generation in the lineage) and beginning with a LATEST shard iterator type. However if you want to process records in order, all future shards you process must be initialized at TRIM_HORIZON.
4. Call GetRecords repeatedly to paginate through a shard. Each GetRecords result includes a nextShardIterator for the next page of results. Rather than calling GetShardIterator any time you'd like to process a specific shard, you only need to call it once to get a valid shard iterator - then you can just continue calling GetRecords until you reach the end of a shard (nextShardIterator is null).

Comment: I didn't find a way to do it in real time. Unless the shard is closed, `nextShardIterator` will always return a none `null` value which make it hard to tell when you finish reading all the items (records array can start empty and then after a few call to return some records again).